# conversion of .wav to array

Tags: java, arrays, wav

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;


public class Audio_to_bytes {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    File WAV_FILE = new File("/home/cybersecurity/Desktop/scream.wav");
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AudioInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(WAV_FILE);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    int read,i;
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
    {
        out.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();
    for(i=0;i<audioBytes.length;i++)
        System.out.println(audioBytes[i]);
}
}
```

The above code is to convert the .wav file into a byte array.When I execute the program i get get many value as -128 or -127,I want to know that whether these values are exact values or the value becomes a boundary value if it exceeds the range of byte(-128 to 128),
if so can i convert the audio file into a integer array since it has a wider range.

Comment: Have u tried serialization concept ?

Comment: Why would the byte become a boundary value? What gave you that idea? The number would roll over.

Comment: i have tried my program with many audio files and i always get the last 100-150 values as -128 or -127 only for all the file
and since i am new to this so thought of asking

Comment: @bmorris591 the thing is that i have to identify scream so i need the exact values for performing fft

Comment: can i convert audio into real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The raw file is irrelevant since WAVE files are constructed using chunks. I suggest understanding those chunks first, [`RIFF` File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format), to understand WAVE files.

Comment: There are tons of specification on the web that shows you that. That is also another question unrelated to your current question.

Comment: I have already answered in the comments under my question that why this conversion is necessary and after searching i found that pcm format could help
so i dont find this unrelated